# Constexpr if alternative

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, c++17

I would like to use `constexpr if` to branch at compile time, but it does not seem to be supported by the latest MSVC compiler. Is there an alternative to the following?:

```
template<typename T>
void MyFunc()
{
    if constexpr(MeetsConditions<T>::value)
    {
        FunctionA<T>();
    }
    else
    {
        FunctionB<T>();
    }
}
```

In short: Can I simulate `constexpr if` when it is not supported by the compiler?

Comment: It's a c++17 feature

Comment: Yes I know, the problem is the newest MSVC does not fully support C++17.

Comment: Might be interesting: [simulate-static_if-with-c11c14](https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2015/07/simulate-static_if-with-c11c14.html)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One of pre-C++17 ways is to use partial template specializations, like here:

```
template <typename T, bool AorB>
struct dummy;

template <typename T, true>
struct dummy {
    static void MyFunc() {  FunctionA<T>(); }
}

template <typename T, false>
struct dummy {
    static void MyFunc() {  FunctionB<T>(); }
}

template <typename T>
void Facade() {
    dummy<T, MeetsConditions<T>::value>::MyFunc();
}
```

If you need more, than 2 specializations - you can use enum or integral value, and make specializations for all needed enums.

Another way is to use std::enable_if:

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if<MeetsConditions<T>::value, void>::type
MyFunc() {
   FunctionA<T>();
}

template <typename T>
std::enable_if<!MeetsConditions<T>::value, void>::type
MyFunc() {
   FunctionB<T>();
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can do it the old fashioned, tried and tested tag dispatch way:

```
template<typename T>
void MyFuncImpl(std::true_type) {
  FunctionA<T>();
}

template<typename T>
void MyFuncImpl(std::false_type) {
  FunctionB<T>();
}

template<typename T>
void MyFunc()
{
  MyFuncImpl<T>(std::integral_constant<bool, MeetsConditions<T>::value>{});
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are using C++ 14 and Boost, consider using [Hana](https://boostorg.github.io/hana/). Implemented using Hana, this looks something like this:

```
template<typename T>
void MyFunc()
{
    hana::eval_if(MeetsConditions<T>::value,
        [](auto) { FunctionA<T>(); },
        [](auto _) { FunctionB<T>(_(exprThatWouldOtherwiseBeAnError)); }
    );
}
```

For the specific case of detecting SFINAE and executing something only in that case, that could be as simple as:

```
template<typename T>
void MyFunc()
{
    auto maybeDoFunctionA = hana::sfinae([]() -> decltype((void) FunctionA<T>()) {
        FunctionA<T>();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 9):

There are several alternatives indeed (which have been in use long before `if constexpr` started to exist).

One is tag dispatch:

```
template <class T>
void Function(std::true_type)
{
  FunctionA<T>();
}

template <class T>
void Function(std::false_type)
{
  FunctionB<T>();
}

template <class T>
void MyFunc()
{
  Function<T>(std::integral_constant<bool, MeetsCondition<T>::value>{});
}
```

Another one are traits:

```
template <bool B>
struct FunctionTraits;

template <>
struct FunctionTraits<true>
{
  template <class T>
  static void Call() { FunctionA<T>(); }
};

template <>
struct FunctionTraits<false>
{
  template <class T>
  static void Call() { FunctionB<T>(); }
};

template <class T>
void MyFunc()
{
  FunctionTraits<MeetsCondition<T>::value>::Call<T>();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

`if constexpr` is a C++17 feature; before C++17, starting from C++11, you can use SFINAE with `std::enable_if`

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<true == MeetsConditions<T>::value>::type MyFunc ()
{ FunctionA<T>(); }

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<false == MeetsConditions<T>::value>::type MyFunc ()
{ FunctionB<T>(); }
```

**-- EDIT --**

If you can use only a C++98 compiler, implement a type traits that work like `std::enable_if` is really simple; see the following example

```
template <bool, typename = void>
struct enableIf
 { };

template <typename T>
struct enableIf<true, T>
 { typedef T type; };
```

and the functions become

```
template<typename T>
typename enableIf<true == MeetsConditions<T>::value>::type MyFunc ()
{ FunctionA<T>(); }

template<typename T>
typename enableIf<false == MeetsConditions<T>::value>::type MyFunc ()
{ FunctionB<T>(); }
```

Comment: SFINAE doesn't require C++11, it was always there in C++.

Comment: @Angew - your right: is `std::enable_if` that is available from C++11, not SFINAE; thanks; answer modified

Comment: There's always `boost::enable_if` if C++11 is not an option.

Comment: @Angew - yes, but I prefer give answer avoiding not-standard api; otherwise, implement a `std::enable_if` like type traits it's so short and simple ... thanks for the suggestion; answer modified

Answer (score 2):

I recently get stuck on that...
So, I created a tiny [`if_constexpr` library](https://github.com/Garcia6l20/if_constexpr14) for back-porting some c++17 code to c++14.

```cpp
#include <if_constexpr.hpp>

template<typename T>
constexpr void MyFunc()
{
    using namespace ic;
    if_<MeetsConditions<T>::value>([] {
        FunctionA<T>();
    }, else_([] {
        FunctionB<T>();
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple answers that solve the problem (as proposed above) but what bother me is that they either require too much code (not reusable) or a dependency (boost.hana et al. ).

I propose a solution that works for me and is reusable. This is C++14 (not C++11 !):

```cpp
        template <typename Bool>
        struct CompileTimeBranch {
        public:
            // v2

            template <typename CallIfTrue>
            static constexpr CompileTimeBranch
            True(CallIfTrue&& to_call_if_true) {
                IfTrue(Bool{}, std::forward<CallIfTrue>(to_call_if_true));
                return CompileTimeBranch{};
            }

            template <typename CallIfFalse>
            static constexpr CompileTimeBranch
            False(CallIfFalse&& to_call_if_false) {
                IfFalse(Bool{}, std::forward<CallIfFalse>(to_call_if_false));
                return CompileTimeBranch{};
            }

            // v1

            template <typename CallIfTrue, typename CallIfFalse>
            static constexpr void
            Then(CallIfTrue&&  to_call_if_true,
                 CallIfFalse&& to_call_if_false) {

                // v2 Re-use True/False
                True(std::forward<CallIfTrue>(to_call_if_true));
                False(std::forward<CallIfFalse>(to_call_if_false));

                // v1 Less verbose but less versatile
                // Branch(Bool{},
                //        std::forward<CallIfTrue>(to_call_if_true),
                //        std::forward<CallIfFalse>(to_call_if_false));
            }

            constexpr operator bool() const {
                return Bool::value;
            }

        protected:
            // v2

            template <typename CallIfTrue>
            static constexpr void
            IfTrue(std::true_type,
                   CallIfTrue&& to_call_if_true) {
                to_call_if_true(Bool{});
            }

            template <typename CallIfTrue>
            static constexpr void
            IfTrue(std::false_type,
                   CallIfTrue&&) {}

            template <typename CallIfFalse>
            static constexpr void
            IfFalse(std::true_type,
                    CallIfFalse&&) {}

            template <typename CallIfFalse>
            static constexpr void
            IfFalse(std::false_type,
                    CallIfFalse&& to_call_if_false) {
                to_call_if_false(Bool{});
            }

            // v1

            // template <typename CallIfTrue, typename CallIfFalse>
            // static constexpr void
            // Branch(std::true_type, CallIfTrue&& to_call_if_true, CallIfFalse&&) {
            //     to_call_if_true(Bool{});
            // }

            // template <typename CallIfTrue, typename CallIfFalse>
            // static constexpr void
            // Branch(std::false_type, CallIfTrue&&, CallIfFalse&& to_call_if_false) {
            //     to_call_if_false(Bool{});
            // }
        };

        template <bool kBranchLiteral>
        using LiteralCompileTimeBranch = CompileTimeBranch<std::integral_constant<bool, kBranchLiteral>>;
```

Usable like so:

```cpp
template <typename T> void AssertIfSmall() {
    static_assert(sizeof(T) <= 4, "");
}

template <typename T> void test0() {
    if (sizeof(T) <= 4) {
        AssertIfSmall<T>(); // Wont compile
        std::printf("Small stuff\n");
    } else {
        std::printf("Big stuff\n");
    }
}

template <typename T> void test1() {
    if constexpr (sizeof(T) <= 4) { // Expected C++17 behavior
        AssertIfSmall<T>();
        std::printf("Small stuff\n");
    } else {
        std::printf("Big stuff\n");
    }
}

template <typename T> void test2() {
    using Branch0 = LiteralCompileTimeBranch<sizeof(T) >= 1>;
    using Branch = LiteralCompileTimeBranch<sizeof(T) <= 4 && Branch0{}>;

    Branch::Then(
        [](auto) {
            AssertIfSmall<T>();
            std::printf("Small stuff\n");
        },
        [](auto) { std::printf("Big stuff\n"); });
}

template <typename T> void test3() {
    using Branch = CompileTimeBranch<std::integral_constant<bool, sizeof(T) <= 4>>;
    Branch::True([](auto) { AssertIfSmall<T>();
                            std::printf("Small stuff\n"); });
    Branch::False([](auto) { std::printf("Big stuff\n"); });
}

template <typename T> void test4() {
    using Branch = CompileTimeBranch<std::integral_constant<bool, sizeof(T) <= 4>>;
    Branch::True([](auto) {
        AssertIfSmall<T>();
        std::printf("Small stuff\n");
    }).False([](auto) {
        std::printf("Big stuff\n");
    });
}
```

Available here as a playground: https://godbolt.org/z/G9snzWqEn