# Template type check parameter C++, different type execution paths

Tags: c++, templates

I'd like slightly different logic in a template based on the template parameter. How might I type check a template parameter?

I have the following which I am surprised does not work:

```
class Bar {
  Bar() {}
}

template <typename T>
void Foo(const &T a) {
  if (!std::is_same<T, Bar>::value) {
    // Do things that will fail for type Bar e.g.
    a.Fail();
  }
}
```

I **do not wish to use template specialization** as in reality template specialization ends up sharing a lot of code for my specific purpose (currently working code is using template specialization)

Currently this fails during compile: `"no member "Fail" in "Bar"`

Comment: Template specialization is the correct solution. Helpful hint: "template specialization" does not mean "duplicate an entire huge function, just to change one small part of it".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each branch should be valid for every type.
In C++17, you could use if constexpr which change that:

```
template <typename T>
void Foo(const &T a) {
  if constexpr (!std::is_same<T, Bar>::value) {
    // Do things that will fail for type Bar e.g.
    a.Fail();
  }
}
```

Before, you have to rely on specialization or overload.
As for example

```
template <typename T>
void Fail(const T& t) { t.Fail(); }

void Fail(const Bar&) { /*Empty*/ }

template <typename T>
void Foo(const &T a) {
    // ...
    Fail(a);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Is there another way to accomplish this same concept in C++11?

Comment: You may look at [constexpr-if-alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43587405/constexpr-if-alternative).

Answer (score 4):

Rather than specializing the entire template function `Foo`, specialize a helper method:

```
template <typename T>
void FooHelper(const T &a) {
    a.fail();
}

template <>
void FooHelper<Bar>(const Bar &a) {
    // something other than a.fail()
}

template <typename T>
void Foo(const T &a) {
    FooHelper<T>(a);
    // etc. etc.
}
```