# C++ Method argument can be either primitive or object

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I have a C++ class `Foo`.  It has a templatized method `setValue()` that needs to accept any of the following as its argument:

- Any primitive type
- An object of type `Bar`
- An object of a subclass of `Bar`

I want to write something like this.

```cpp
template <class T>
void setValue(T& value) {
    if (std::is_fundamental<T>::value)
        setPrimitiveValue(value)
    else {
        Bar* bar = dynamic_cast<Bar*>(&value);
        if (bar != NULL)
            setBarValue(*bar);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't compile.  When I call the method with an `int`, the compiler complains that `dynamic_cast` can't be used on an `int*`.  Even though that code branch doesn't get executed for primitives, the compiler still needs to compile it.

How can I make this work?  Note this is a method in a class, so template specializations aren't allowed.

Comment: You have many possibilities: **1** You can always simulate template specialization by forwarding the call to a class. **2** You can have an overload that take a `Bar *` as its argument. **3** You can also use SFINAE (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae). **4** `constexpr` answer is also a possibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since *C++17* you can easily address this problem with [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if).

As you can expect, it can exclude an entire branch from the *compilation* (rather than the execution, as a normal `if`).

*Note*: the code is still subjected to syntax rules. Details are out of the scope of this answer.

```
template <class T>
void setValue(T& value) {
    if constexpr (std::is_fundamental<T>::value)
        setPrimitiveValue(value)
    else {
        Bar* bar = dynamic_cast<Bar*>(&value);
        if (bar != NULL)
            setBarValue(*bar);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Biagio Festa looks perfect as long as you can use C++17.  I can't since I still need to support older compilers, but that answer led me to [Constexpr if alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43587405/constexpr-if-alternative) which gives several alternatives.  Here's the solution I ended up with which works even on C++11.

```cpp
template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value, void>::type setValue(T& value) {
    setPrimitiveValue(value);
}

void setValue(Bar& value) {
    setBarValue(value);
}
```