# GENERIC solution for replacing if constexpr in C++14

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, template-meta-programming, boost-hana

Firstly, I have already seen [Constexpr if alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43587405/), but that didn't help.

I updated the post to clarify explicitly the necessity of the generic solution.
What I need is a generic solution to use the potential of C++17 `if constexpr` in C++14. Maybe, we can do something with `lambdas` and/or `boost::hana` here?

Below you will find a small example of using `if constexpr` - I don't need the solution for the below-mentioned case only - rather a generic one, that can be applied in most cases as the replacement of `if constexpr` if not everywhere.
You can assume I am porting C++17 code with `if constexpr` to C++14 - what is the simplest way of doing that?

I am thinking of solution, which might look like below, but not sure how to implement that:
`if<condition>(func1).elif<condition2>(func2).else(func3)`
Other ideas are highly welcome as well.

C++17 code to test:

```cpp
#include <string>
template<class T>
constexpr bool value = true;

template<>
constexpr bool value<std::string> = false;

template<class T>
void method(const T& arg) {
    if constexpr (value<T>) {
        if (!arg) return;
    }
    //mylogic(arg);
}

int main() {
    std::string arg;
    method(arg);

    int arg2;
    method(arg2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `if (conditional_conversion_to_bool<value>(arg)) return;` and specialize `conditional_conversion_to_bool<true>` to convert its argument and `conditional_conversion_to_bool<false>` to simply return `false` with argument unused?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. How to convert code which do not have enough context? Example what it is the `value`? template parameter, some global constant. What is the type of it?

Comment: @MarekR, I added example upon the request.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I agree that template specialization using SFINAE principal will work, but can it be done in more simple manner using boost::hana?

Comment: I was not suggesting SFINAE, just template specialization.

Comment: @BenVoigt, clear, my bad, but can we apply boost::hana::eval_if to avoid creation of the additional classes?

Answer (score 2):

You can just do it the old fashioned way with `std::enable_if` by moving the type dependent code into a separate function with specialisations:

```
#include <string>
template<class T>
constexpr bool value = true;

template<>
constexpr bool value<std::string> = false;

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<value<T>, bool> = true>
bool is_unset(const T& arg)
{
    return !arg;
}

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<!value<T>, bool> = true>
bool is_unset(const T& arg)
{
    return false;
}

template<class T>
void method(const T& arg) {
    if (is_unset<T>(arg)) {
        return;
    }
    //mylogic(arg);
}

int main() {
    std::string arg;
    method(arg);

    int arg2;
    method(arg2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks.
But assuming I have multiple "if constexpr" with different logic, I want a generic solution for that kind of problem.

Maybe, one with lambdas...

Comment: It's important when creating an example code for a question to include all the requirements, this code implements the example as given

Comment: I added "I need a scalable solution for replacing if constexpr - not the one for solving this case only." soon after creating the example.

Comment: @HlibPylypets That's a rather vague description. In order to not rely on vague descriptions, we need an example that demonstrates your use case. If your example function had 5 different `constexpr` use cases, you wouldn't get 2 "not scalable" answers. Please update the question so it includes all the requirements in the [mre] you have there.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili, I am not sure how to provide all the potential examples of using "if constexpr", but I found something useful here - https://github.com/wichtounet/cpp_utils/blob/master/static_if.hpp

It looks quite similar to the solution I was looking for...

Comment: @HlibPylypets looks like a solid idea. C++17 transition will also be smoother. It would be nice to add a self-answer summarizing that for future reference. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here is [mcve to start with](https://godbolt.org/z/h9nrvT5nv).

There are couple ways to fix it.

Now since you created `value` template to do special treatment of `std:string` it can be achieved by simple overload:

```cpp
template<class T>
void method(const T& arg) {
    if (!arg) return;
    mylogic(arg);
}

void method(const std::string& arg) {
    mylogic(arg);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/PeWdbadxK

Now assuming that `value` is something more complex it can go like this:

```cpp
template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<value<T>> method(const T& arg) {
    if (!arg) return;
    mylogic(arg);
}

template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<!value<T>> method(const T& arg) {
    mylogic(arg);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Mjvfr7qqb

Apparently you are trying to handle case that `T` can't be converted to `bool`, so you can make this this way:

```cpp
template<class...>
using void_t = void;

template<class T, class U = void>
constexpr bool value = false;

template<class T>
constexpr bool value<T, void_t<decltype(!std::declval<T>())>> = true;

template<typename T>
void mylogic(T&& arg)
{
    std::cout << std::forward<T>(arg) << '\n';
}

template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<value<T>> method(const T& arg) {
    if (!arg) return;
    mylogic(arg);
}

template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<!value<T>> method(const T& arg) {
    mylogic(arg);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/46n87xd6a

Comment: Thanks, I updated the post - I need a generic solution to replace a lot of possible if constexpr usages from C++17 in C++14.

Is there a way to do that in a less verbose manner?